# Display Label.Text from an ADO SQL Connection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ado

This was originally one question with two parts. A SQL issue and a Visual Studio issue. I've broken it into separate questions now and this is the one with VS C# issue.

I want to display the values using visual studio on some label.text and am running into some issues. Here is a picture of the form and what happens when I try to run my current code.

[image]
[image]

Here is my current c# code from the Form1.cs code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=Historian;Database=Runtime;User Id=sa;Password=Historian2015!!;";
    conn = new ADODB.Connection();
    conn.Open(str, "", "", -1);  // connection Open

    playTrend_Click_1(sender, e);

    Timer tmr = new Timer();
    tmr.Interval = 1000;//ticks every 1 second
    tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
    tmr.Start();
}

private void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();
    sql = "SELECT TOP 2 [DateTime] ,[TagName] ,[Value] FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[v_StringHistory] WHERE [TagName] = 'ERecipeRunning' OR [TagName] = 'PRecipeRunning'";
    // RECORDSET OPEN
    rs.Open(sql, conn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockBatchOptimistic, 0);

    lbPCurrRecipeV.Text = rs.Fields[2].Value.ToString();
    lbECurrRecipeV.Text = rs.Fields[2].Value.ToString();
}

private void playTrend_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ccEa = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0x80, 0x00);
    var ccEb = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0xcb, 0x97);
    var ccPa = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0x00, 0x80, 0xc0);
    var ccPb = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0xb0, 0xe6, 0xff);

    lbPCurrRecipeV.ForeColor = ccPa;
    lbPCurrRecipeV.BackColor = ccPb;
    lbPCurrRecipeT.ForeColor = ccPb;
    lbPCurrRecipeT.BackColor = ccPa;

    lbECurrRecipeV.ForeColor = ccEa;
    lbECurrRecipeV.BackColor = ccEb;
    lbECurrRecipeT.ForeColor = ccEb;
    lbECurrRecipeT.BackColor = ccEa;
}
```

}

How do I get the values for each into the respective labels? On the original thread, they did advise me to switch from ADODB to ADO.NET. Anyone got any ideas about how I can reference the sql values?

Comment: What's ADODB again? :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in was indeed related to the ADODB connection I was using. I found the [answer here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_28264645.html). Basically it was a matter of changing some settings in the ADODB properties. Had to change Embed Interop Types to False and then make Copy Local True. That fixed me up.

Now it's a matter of fixing my sql string and I'll be good to go. And I plan to investigate using the ADO.net methods tomorrow as you guys suggested.

[image]